# Wait until application.run is completed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro on one file that opens another workbook, runs a macro to get some data, copies the data into the first workbook and closes the second workbook.

I have however encountered a problem because it seems like the selection of the range is executed while the macro in the second workbook is still running and therefore selects the entire column:

i.e. the `ws2.Range(StartCell, ws2.Cells(LastRow, "A")).Select` string in the code below selects the whole column, and not just the cells where there is data.

```
'run macro in IB API file to get portfolio data
Application.Run "TwsDde.xls!Sheet15.subscribeToPorts"

'select data in column A from IB API file
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A8")
LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlDown).Row
ws2.Range(StartCell, ws2.Cells(LastRow, "A")).Select
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before or has any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: `Application.Run` is expected to return the value returned by the called macro (here `subscribeToPorts`), so it is not an asynchronous call by itself. Is there any asynchronous calls inside the macro?

Comment: The macro that is called is developed by the a broker and all it does is get the data from my portfolio into Excel. Do you have any suggestions on how this could be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of `LastRow` is wrong. It should be `xlUp` instead of `xlDown`.

Comment: There is another issue: It refers to `StartCell.Column` which refers to `Set StartCell = Range("A8")` which is exactly the same as `Set StartCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A8")` and which should be `Set StartCell = ws2.Range("A8")` to work safe and without issues. It's a good practice to *never* assume the worksheet, and reference to a specific worksheet with every `.Range`, `.Rows`, `.Columns`, `.Cells` etc.

Comment: I have used xlDown because I want to select and copy everything from A8 downwards - is it wrong?

I have tried to change the StartCell.Column, but this does not solve the problem

Comment: Yes, then you made a mistake. To achieve what you said you should do `LastRow = StartCell.End(xlDown).Row` (which means "from `StartCell` go down to the end of block of data and take the row number from that cell").

Comment: What you have now means "in sheet `ws2` from cell that has row number equal to the number of all rows in sheet and column number equal to the column number of `StartCell`, go down and take row number of that cell".

Comment: Many thanks! 
Do you know what could be causing the other error? i.e. the macro run with application.run takes a few seconds to fill in the data in the sheet, but the selection process happens before the data is filled in. Therefore I have all cells from A8 onwards selected...